# how to delete file name "sample note.txt" in linux terminal

Tags: linux

how to delete text file or director which name like "sample folder/sample note.txt" thru Linux terminal

```
file location - /home
file name - sample folder
text file name - sample text.txt
```

Comment: Are you asking how to delete files with a space in their names? Simply put the name in quotes. `rm 'my file.txt'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the backslash to remove the folder.

```
rm sample\ folder
```

Though you can also use

```
rm "sample folder"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove files with names containing spaces (or most other strange characters) with using single quotes around the file name, e.g.

```
rm 'sample folder/sample note.txt'
```

If unsure, it is good practice to try with `ls` first. If `ls` lists the correct file (and *only* the correct file), then switch to using `rm`.

Comment: This is good advice.  You can also use the back slash character to "escape" the space (which means the space will be treated literally instead of as a separator).

I.E. rm sample\ folder/sample\ note.txt

Answer (score 1):

In the prompt, most of the time you can just let the command completion enter the escaped characters for you. So if you have a `Sample Directory` and no `SampleAnything`, entering <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will complete to `Sample\` or even `Sample\ Directory/`.

In other cases you can also sidestep the problem by replacing the space by a `?` which is the single-character wildcard (`*` would also work but is riskier since it can potentially match more things): `Sample?Directory/Sample?File.txt`.

Of course in a script, you use quotes.